# Sass - Accesing father from another file

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm using sass and react in my project and I have the Menu component and the MenuItem component, each of them has a different scss file.
In the menu.scss I have certain behavior for :hover, and I want to have a different behavior in the menuItem.scss from the menu.scss :hover.
Can I access somehow to the father from the menuItem.scss?

Comment: Can you post what code you have and maybe something to show what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your scss is a bit weird imo. 
Just target it with `.menu .menuItem`?